# Android Barcode API - scan QR code at 15-45 degree angle

Tags: android, rotation, android-camera, qr-code, google-vision

I'm trying to figure out how I can scan a QR code that has a 15-45 degree orientation using the live camera preview to decode it.

I have a sample that I've created using a static image that simply rotates the image through an array of predefined degrees before trying to decode the image. This works, but I'd like to achieve a similar result using the live preview instead of a pre-loaded image.

I'm using the following barcode API: https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview

**Working Sample using a Pre-loaded Image**

```
Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);
int[] angles = { 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 90 };
int cacheAngle = 0;


    while(barcodes.size() == 0) {
        //try to get code

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
                myBitmap = rotateImage(myBitmap, angles[i]);
                myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                myImageView.invalidate(); //re-draw image

                Log.d(TAG, "Trying angle: " + angles[i]);
                cacheAngle = i;
                updateConsole("Trying scan at angle: " + angles[i] + "...");
                frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
                barcodes = detector.detect(frame);

                if (barcodes.size() > 0) {
                    updateConsole("Barcode found at angle: " + angles[i]);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Hooray, barcode found: " + barcodes.valueAt(0).rawValue);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(barcodes.size() == 0) {
                //failed to detect barcode during rotations
                updateConsole("Error: Failed to detect barcode!");
                updateConsole("[Reason] Image resolution may be too large, small or blurry!");
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
            updateConsole("Fatal Exception [Out Of Memory]");
            updateConsole("Can't decode bitmap, image is probably too large!");
            updateConsole("Angles tested before crash: ");
            for(int x=0; x<angles.length; x++){
                if(angles[x] <= cacheAngle){
                    updateConsole(angles[x] + " degrees");
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

**Live Preview Barcode Capture - not working on 15-45 degree oriented QR code**

used sample code from here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680

However, I'm not finding anything in the API that would allow me to rotate the angle at which the camera would try to scan the code.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I read through the documentation and it looks like there aren't any methods that exist for this purpose. However, not all hope is lost! One option would be to grab a Bitmap object from the camera view every 1000 milliseconds or so and run your  "Pre-loaded image" code on each bitmap you capture until you find a match. If you would like to give this a shot, talk to me on Upwork. I'm Tim Bird.

Comment: I also have plenty of experience implementing this process in a way that doesn't compromise the integrity of your app. I don't want to give too much of my solution away but I can assure you that your app will still run smoothly even with this process running in your app.